# strip data frame cell then create columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to take the info from dataframe and break it out into columns with the following header names. the info is all crammed into 1 cell.

new to python, so be gentle.

thanks for the help

my code:

```
r=requests.get('https://nclbgc.org/search/licenseDetails?licenseNumber=80479')

page_data = soup(r.text, 'html.parser')
company_info = [' '.join(' '.join(info.get_text(", ", strip=True).split()) for info in page_data.find_all('tr'))]
df = pd.DataFrame(company_info, columns = ['ic_number, status, renewal_date, company_name, address, county, telephon, limitation, residential_qualifiers'])


print(df)
```

the result i get:

```
['License Number, 80479 Status, Valid Renewal Date, n/a  Name, DLR Construction, LLC Address, 3217 Vagabond Dr Monroe, N
C 28110 County, Union Telephone, (980) 245-0867 Limitation, Limited Classifications, Residential Qualifiers, Arteaga, Vi
cky Rodriguez']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) with some post processing:

```
url = 'https://nclbgc.org/search/licenseDetails?licenseNumber=80479'

#select first table form list of tables, remove only NaNs rows
df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(how='all')
#forward fill NaNs in first column
df[0] = df[0].ffill()
#merge values in second column
df = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())).to_frame().rename_axis(None).T

print (df)
                             Address Classifications County License Number  \
1  3217 Vagabond Dr Monroe, NC 28110     Residential  Union          80479   

  Limitation                   Name                Qualifiers Renewal Date  \
1    Limited  DLR Construction, LLC  Arteaga, Vicky Rodriguez                

  Status       Telephone  
1  Valid  (980) 245-0867
```

Comment: jezrael, thanks so much.  works great.  python is driving me a little crazy. would you have a recommendation as to where i can find some info on how you went about this.  I want to make sure that i understand why and how it worked.

Comment: @RobK - I dont know som really easy solution for your problem, I like [this](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/) - especially comments under each lesson

Comment: actually going through "the hardway" right now.  guess i'm on the right track.

Comment: i just ran the updated code and it dropped the first column "icense_number"

Comment: take that back, all columns are there as they should be.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: here's one of the urls:  https://nclbgc.org/search/licenseDetails?licenseNumber=80479

Comment: Ok, I see answer, it should be problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the df line like below:

df = pd.DataFrame(company_info, columns = ['ic_number', 'status', 'renewal_date', 'company_name', 'address', 'county', 'telephon', 'limitation', 'residential_qualifiers'])

Each column mentioned under columns should be within quotes. Else it is considered as one single column.